# Blank Nvidia server settings in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, xorg

Recently I installed Kubuntu on my laptop HP Pavilion 15ec0062ax. Everything works fine except when I open nvidia settings it looks like this

[image: mostly black screen]

and when I run `nvidia-smi` in command line this is the output:

```
Wed Jul 22 19:34:16 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  3020MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvdia-settings` output

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:3248): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:35:07.539: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 19:35:07.542: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 19:35:07.542: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

`nvidia-xconfig` output:

```
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.


WARNING: Unable to parse X.Org version string.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found

ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.
```

I have tried reinstalling the driver, adding repo or manually executing the run file but the problem persists.

Is there a way to solve the issue?